# <<closed>>This condition will always return 'false' since JavaScript compares objects by reference, not value, what does this mean in the Scenario?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

in TS 4.9.3 and angular 15 application, i have a service function isEmpty() with following snippet of code.

```
    static isEmpty(value: any): boolean {
        if (value === null || value === undefined || value === {} || value === []) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and it generates **`This condition will always return 'false' since JavaScript compares objects by reference, not value.`** issue for conditions `value === {}` and `value === []`.

Comment: It means what it says: there's no point to the comparison as it will always be false so your function always returns undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error states, in JavaScript `object`s are compared by reference. So you cannot compare object values like `{} === {}`. Something like this will always return `false` because both `{}` have different memory addresses.

In your case you compare an argument `value` to a newly created object (`{}`). The condition will always return `false` since there is no way for the objects to have the same reference. TypeScript detects this and warns you about this by showing an compiler error. Also the TypeScript control-flow analysis notices that the function never returns the annotated return type `boolean` resulting in another compiler error.

This feature was added in [TypeScript 4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html) ([Errors When Comparing Object and Array Literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#errors-when-comparing-object-and-array-literals))

> [...] We believe that similar code in JavaScript is at best an early foot-gun for JavaScript developers, and at worst a bug in production code. That’s why TypeScript now disallows code like the following.